# awk to match on keyword and check sub pattern of another field

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to print the entire line, along with the header row, if `$3` is `SNV or MNV or INDEL`. If that condition is met or it true, then in `$4` the `sub` pattern `:GMAF=` is found and the value after the = sign is checked. If that value is less than or equal to .01 then the entire line, along with header row, is printed.

Since it is possible for `$3` to be `SNV` and `$4` to be blank or null, then I am not sure how to capture this as well. Line 2 is an example of this. The assumption is that if there is no value in `$4` then this is the same as zero so may be significant and is extracted. I am also not sure how to include the header row minus the `#` in the print. The `---` are not part of the file, they are just there to indicate the header. I added comments to each line as well.  Thank you :).

**file**  `tab-delimited`

```
##.....
##.....
#ID Name    Func    List     ---- header row ----
1   1   REF 
2   2   SNV 
3   3   SNV AMAF=0.0041:EMAF=0.0:GMAF=0.0014
```

**desired output**  `tab-delimited`

```
ID  Name    Func    List
2   2   SNV 
3   3   SNV AMAF=0.0041:EMAF=0.0:GMAF=0.0014
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR>3   # define FS and OFS as tab and look in 3 row of file  
        $3 == "SNV"|| $3 == "MNV"|| $3 == "INDEL"{   # start block and look in row 3 in`$2` for any of these words
        sub(/:GMAF=*/,"",$4);  # if found then search `$4` for `:GMAF=`
        VAL=substr($4,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4);   3 extract the 4 digits after the = sign as VAL
                                             }  # close block
            for(i=1;i<=num;i++){   # create a loop to iterate over each line as i
                    if(VAL[i] <= 0.01){  3 check each VAL in iand if less then or equal to 0.01
                    {  # start block
                                    print $1, $2, $3, VAL;  # print output
                                      }  # end block
                next   # process next line
                }  # end block
                1' file
```

---

Edit by Ed Morton just to format the above code to be easier to understand:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '                           # define FS and OFS as tab
    NR>3                                           # and look in 3 row of file

    $3 == "SNV" || $3 == "MNV" || $3 == "INDEL" {  # start block and look in row 3 in`$2` for any of these words
        sub(/:GMAF=*/,"",$4);                      # if found then search `$4` for `:GMAF=`
        VAL=substr($4,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4);         3 extract the 4 digits after the = sign as VAL
    }                                              # close block

    for(i=1;i<=num;i++) {                          # create a loop to iterate over each line as i
        if(VAL[i] <= 0.01) {                       3 check each VAL in iand if less then or equal to 0.01
            {                                      # start block
                print $1, $2, $3, VAL;             # print output
            }                                      # end block
            next                                   # process next line
        }                                          # end block
1' file
```

Comment: I modified the white space and indenting in your script so the flow of the code is much easier to see. Now you can easily see all the syntax and semantic errors (missing braces, extra braces, missing comment start chars, etc.) so just fix them and then come back if you still have a problem. Indentation and white space are extremely important in software, find a good standard to follow and then just do that. Oh, and don't use all upper case variable names to avoid clashes with builtin variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

To catch the case that `$4` is unset/blank/non existing, that would mean for awk that total number of fields is 3 (`NF==3`)

To delete the `#` in front of header row, you can use any subsitute technique (i.e sub). I used gensub in my test.

Full answer:
The bellow code seems that fits to your needs. Though i have not used a tab-delimited file, but you can adjust accordingly to your tabulated file.

```
$ cat file4
##.....
##.....
#ID Name    Func    List
1   1   REF 
2   2   SNV 
3   3   SNV AMAF=0.0041:EMAF=0.0:GMAF=0.0014
4   4   RNV AMAF=0.0041:EMAF=0.0:GMAF=0.0014
5   5   SNV AMAF=0.0041:EMAF=0.0:GMAF=0.14
6   6   INDEL
7   7   RNV
8   8   SNV GMAF=0.0041:EMAF=0.0:AMAF=0.0014
9   9   SNV EMAF=0.0041:GMAF=0.1:AMAF=0.0014

$ awk 'NR<3{next}NR==3{print gensub(/^#/,"","1");next}($3 == "SNV"|| $3 == "MNV"|| $3 == "INDEL") && NF==3{print;next}       
($3 == "SNV"|| $3 == "MNV"|| $3 == "INDEL") {val=gensub(/.*GMAF=(.[^:]*).*/,"\\1","g",$4);if (val<=0.1) print}' file4
ID  Name    Func    List
2   2   SNV 
3   3   SNV AMAF=0.0041:EMAF=0.0:GMAF=0.0014
6   6   INDEL
8   8   SNV GMAF=0.0041:EMAF=0.0:AMAF=0.0014
9   9   SNV EMAF=0.0041:GMAF=0.1:AMAF=0.0014
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'NR<3{next}                                                       # skip the first two lines
     NR==3{print gensub(/^#/,"","1");next}                            # print the third line (header) by removing the leading #
     ($3 == "SNV"|| $3 == "MNV"|| $3 == "INDEL") && NF==3{print;next} # Print the lines missing $4 and go to next line    
     ($3 == "SNV"|| $3 == "MNV"|| $3 == "INDEL") {                    # if $3 fullfils the criteria then
        val=gensub(/.*GMAF=(.[^:]*).*/,"\\1","g",$4);                 # isolate the value of GMAF with regex
        if (val<=0.1) print;                                          # compare and print
        }' file4
```

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you Ed for your valuable comments. I updated my answer including most of your advises.

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure why you wouldn't use `$3 == "SNV" || $3 == "MNV" || $3 == "INDEL" { if (NF!=3) {val=gensub(/.*GMAF=(.[^:]*).*/,"\\1","g",$4); if (val>0.1) next} print }` or similar to save specifying the same code twice though.

Comment: Thank you both :).